# Compiling expo app: Cannot find symbol VoicePackage

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm compiling an expo app using `npx expo run:android` (Testing on an android emulator). However, I got this error:

```
C:\Users\wilbu\Projects\ASLTranslator\ASLTranslator\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
import com.reactnative.voice.VoicePackage;
                            ^
  symbol:   class VoicePackage
  location: package com.reactnative.voice
C:\Users\wilbu\Projects\ASLTranslator\ASLTranslator\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
      new VoicePackage(),
          ^
  symbol:   class VoicePackage
  location: class PackageList
2 errors
```

I couldn't find any similar questions but it does appear to be a problem when importing the package.
I'm using gradle 8.0.1 with JDK 11.